# Matching and reconstructing a pair of strings in Python based on a conditional

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, pattern-matching

I have the following pair of short strings in Python3.x, whose lengths must be equal:

```
string_a = 'he_lo_world'
string_b = 'hi_low_oldd'
```

I would like to *quickly as possible* create a "summary string" based on how the characters in the pair match, given the following rules:

(1) If the characters are the same, the new letter is S (same). Unless the matching characters are `_`, then it is U (underscore).

(2) Otherwise, the characters don't match. If there's no match, the letter is N (no match). If `string_a` has `_` and `string_b` does not, it is `A`. If `string_b` has `_` and `string_a` does not, it is `B`.

For the pair above, the string would be:

```
SNUSSABSNNS
```

To construct this string, I think multiple if/for statements will be too inefficient.

Using the list comprehension and itertools example here, [Trying to find a match in two strings - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717142/trying-to-find-a-match-in-two-strings-python)

```
import itertools
string_a = 'he_lo_world'
string_b = 'hi_low_oldd'

same = [ i for i,x in enumerate(itertools.izip(string_a,string_b)) if all(y==x[0] for y in x)]

print(same) ## [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10]
```

I can get the indices of the matches. (The `_==_` exception would require a conditional in the list comprehension, so index 2 shouldn't exist above.)

I'm confused how (A) to re-construct a string based on this list of indices and (B) how do I efficiently deal with non-matching characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
string_a = 'he_lo_world'
string_b = 'hi_low_oldd'
new_s = ''.join(['S', 'U'][a == '_'] if a == b else 'N' if a != '_' and b != '_' else ['A', 'B'][b == '_' and a != '_'] for a, b in zip(string_a, string_b))
```

Output:

```
'SNUSSABSNNS'
```